# P-table not sorting numbers with dots (version numbers) properly

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, p-table

I am using Angular 12 and I have a problem with `p-table` that I doesn't have an idea how to solve since in some examples it is working properly - in some it doesn't.

**Working example with item list:**
item1: V3
item2: V2.5
item3: V2.0
item4: V1.5

**Example when it doesn't work:**
item1: V1.5
item2: V1.3
item3: V1.0

So, from the examples, we can see that it is not working only in a situation where all items starts with same number V1.. but when there is a different starting value, it is working-sorting normally.